# How do I duplicate this string in C?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to generate 2 strings, of which the second one should be a loop of the first one.

Example:

```
input 1(key) = passw
input 2(str) = mymessagemymessage
output 1(keyloop) = passwpasspasswpass
output 2(str) = mymessagemymessage
```

The problem here is not to generate `keyloop` but actually to keep input 2 unchanged. My current output looks like this:

```
output 1(keyloop) = passwpasspasswpass 
output 2(str) = passwpasspasswpass **<-- not the desired output**
```

This is the code:

```
    int main (int argc, string argv[])
    {

        string key = argv[1];
        int k = 0;

        string str = GetString();

        string keyloop = str;

        for (int i=0; i<strlen(keyloop); i++)
        {
            if ( k == strlen(key))
            {
                k = 0;
                keyloop[i]=key[k];
                k++;                    
            }
            else if (k != strlen(key))
            {
                keyloop[i]=key[k];
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("error");
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", keyloop);
        printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

What's up with my code and how should I change it?

Comment: What is this `string`? This is not valid in C.

Comment: @jpo38 Probably typedef char* string;

Comment: @YotamSalmon: Probably. What a terrible idea to do that....because then `keyloop = str;` looks to be such a valid string copy operation...when it's not!

Comment: `typedef char* string` is a terrible idea. Don't do this, all it does is adding confusion and make wrong code look correct.

Comment: @jpo38 I have never said it was a good idea

Comment: @YotamSalmon: Sure, but it had to be said that it was terrible ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've managed to deduce from your parameters in `main` that `string` is a `typedef` for `char*` (or a `const char*`, but that would have caused compiler errors later on). If not then the behaviour of your program is *undefined* due to to a malformed `main` prototype. If would have been *wonderful* if you'd told us that ;-)

Moving on, `string keyloop = str;` therefore only takes a *shallow copy* of `str`, so changes in one "string" will affect the other one since they point to the same buffer!

A fix? Use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, or `strdup` instead. If you use `strdup` then remember it's *your* job to call `free` once you're done with the copy.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I forgot to mention the string.h library I included. The issue was quickly resolved using strcpy, like this: strcpy(keyloop, str);